# Android activity transition does not appear

Tags: android, material-design, activity-transition

I have been trying for some months to get an activity transition to work. I have tried a number of approaches, using XML and styles, and code, to no avail.  Below is my most recent attempt. Does anyone know why I can't get any transitions to appear?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addSlideTransitions();
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_layout);
    ....
}

protected void addSlideTransitions()
{
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
    Slide slide = new Slide();
    slide.setDuration(1000);
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(slide);
    getWindow().setExitTransition(slide);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must start the activity with an ActivityOptions bundle created with makeSceneTransitionAnimation.

That type of transition also only works when in the same task (as of N).

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this,I am sure this will work for you.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addSlideTransitions();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }



    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    protected void addSlideTransitions()
    {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
        Slide slide = new Slide();
        slide.setDuration(1000);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(slide);
        getWindow().setExitTransition(slide);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't solve it this time, but thanks for trying!

Comment: what is the actual error you are getting? @Sparklellama

Comment: I'm not getting an error.  What I'm finding is that I always get the default android activity transition animation, and adding this new code has no apparent effect.  Logging and breakpoints show the code is being run, but it appears to be ineffectual.

Comment: Do you want to customize the activity transition along with the Views and Viewgroups?@Sparklellama

Comment: You must start the activity with an ActivityOptions bundle created with makeSceneTransitionAnimation.

Comment: @CrazyAndroid my intention is to create the effect of new activities sliding in from the right, and the old ones sliding out to the left - or anything close to that, by any means possible. From GIF animations I've seen on tutorial sites, this approach will give me something similar to what I'm looking for. But I'd prefer a basic full screen sliding effect, like scrolling to the left, if it were possible.

Comment: @GeorgeMount Your answer is correct, if you copy it into a response, I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the call to `addSlideTransitions` before `super.onCreate`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    addSlideTransitions();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_layout);
    ....
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't solve it this time, but thanks for trying!